# Angular 2 modules with the same path

Tags: angular

There are 2 modules which have the same path but different templates (main and auth). It is necessary that the modules load regarding whether the user is authenticated or not. Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way.

There are codes

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './core/services/auth.service';

var authService = new AuthService()

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren:() => authService.isAuth ?    import('./modules/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule) : import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main.router.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...

const routes = [
    {path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'dashboard', component: MainPageComponent},
        {path: 'payments', component: PaymentPageComponent},
        {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
        {path: 'cards', component: CardsComponent},
        {path: 'accounts', component: AccountsComponent},
        {path: 'loans', component: LoansComponent},
        {path: 'deposits', component: DepositsComponent},
        {path: 'extracts-and-reports', component: ExtractsAndReportsComponent},
        {path: 'payroll', component: PayrollComponent},
        {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
        {path: 'confirm', component: PaymentAccessComponent},
        {path: 'mailbox', component: MailboxComponent},
        {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
    ]}
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class MainRouter { }
```

auth.router.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...

const routes = [
    {path: '', component: AuthComponent, children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent}
    ]}
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AuthRouter { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular router has a method called [resetConfig()](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetconfig) which allows you to replace the route configuration. You use one configuration when the app loads, and when you detect that the user has authenticated, you can replace it with a configuration that loads the other module.

So basically you will have two route configs:

```js
const routesDefault: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren:() => import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)}
];

const routesAuth: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren:() => import('./modules/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routesDefault)
    ],
    ...
```

And then somewhere in your code, whenever you detect that the user has authenticated, do this:

```
router.resetConfig(routesAuth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question, one possible workaround is to use two different `router-outlets` one for the authenticated case and one for the non-authenticated case.

```html
<router-outlet name="auth"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="notAuth"></router-outlet>
```

In your router config, your routing should describe also the name of the outlet, like so

```js
{
    path: 'the-path',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./authenticated/authenticated.module').then(
        m => m.AuthenticatedModule
      ),
    outlet: 'auth'
  },
  {
    path: 'the-path',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./unauthorized/unauthorized.module').then(
        m => m.UnauthorizedModule
      ),
    outlet: 'notAuth'
  },
```

and the way you will specify your navigation (to the auth or notAuth paths) will look something like so

```js
  naviagetToThePath() {
    if (this.isAuth) {
      this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { auth: ['the-path'] } }]);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { notAuth: ['the-path'] } }]);
    }
  }
```

So technically with this solution, you are using the same path, but actually, in the URL you will be seeing different strings, which might be an undesired side effects.

Here is a working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gugk7x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the described solution, that also includes a guard.